# Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer@1.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.2@aar

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Could you explain how this is related to Crashlytics? If you temporarily remove Firebase and Crashlytics, do you still get this error?

Comment: It not related to firebase migration. Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the above error by upgrading the version to latest 3.3.0
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter.sdk.android/tweet-composer/3.3.0